# File made in Dockerfile lost when exec docker run with "-v /path:/path" params

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mkdir, docker-volume

I am in trouble with **docker volume**. I want to `mkdir` directory and `touch` file in it within the **Dockerfile**.

When I exec `docker run -it --name any_name` with `-v /path:/path image_name` params, the directory and file made in Dockerfile are both lost.

For example:

Dockerfile for build image BB:tag.

```
FROM AA:tag

RUN set -ex \
    && mkdir -p /var/log/my_directory/ \
    && touch /var/log/my_directory/my_file.log

CMD ["anything_cmd"]
```

If I exec

```
docker run -it --name any_name BB:tag
```

my_directory and my_file.log are both there.

But if I exec

```
docker run -it --name any_name -v /var/log/container_logs/any_name:/var/log/ BB:tag
```

my_directory and my_file.log are both missing.

What happened to it with `-v` when `docker run`? and what's the best practice to do such kind of thing?

Comment: what is `/path` here is it `/var/log/my_directory` ?

Comment: @mchawre sorry for the unclear commands. I update it and now it's clear.

Comment: This is analogous to mounting an empty usb drive onto a folder that already has files in it, if you list the files in the directory it'll appear as empty. The files that exist in the directory are only available after unmounting the empty usb drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Steps inside the Dockerfile are used to create the image.
- The `docker run` command takes the image and creates a container.
- Mounting a volume (the `-v` argument) will bind mount a directory into the container in a given location. And host mounts do not have any initialization step on that volume.

Therefore, it's expected to only see files from `/var/log/container_logs/any_name` on the host inside the container at `/var/log/`.

---

If you need to initialize a volume, there are a few options:

1. You can use a named volume rather than a host volume. This will be initialized, but only when that named volume is empty. Once it has files in the named volume, docker will not initialize it again since that could result in data loss.
2. You can use an entrypoint script inside your container to copy files from a saved location into the volume location. This saved location inside your image cannot be overlaid with a volume, otherwise you will have the same issue.

---

If you want a named volume pointing to a host directory, you can use the local volume driver (this is the default) with options to bind mount a specific directory. Various methods to implement that include:

```
  # create the volume in advance
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=none \
      --opt device=/home/user/test \
      --opt o=bind \
      test_vol

  # create on the fly with --mount
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/home/user/test \
    foo

  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    bind-test:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /home/user/test
  ...
```

---

And if you want to use an entrypoint script, see the volume caching description in [my base image repo](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base).

Comment: Thanks to help me understand the volume. But still some troubles when I try it. I want to create several containers(for example `container_a`, `container_b`, `container_c`) all based on the image `BB:tag`, every container has it's own `/var/log`. And in the host `/var/log/container_logs/` directory, you can see `container_a`, `container b`, `container_c`. Now I can create `/var/log/container_logs/` as volume, but when and where I write the codes to create the directory `container_a`, `container_b` and `container_c`?

Comment: I solve it by add the docker-entrypoint.sh file. Thanks very much.